# How to close a modal

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a modal that displays when the page is accessed. When the button is clicked on *Auth* the modal should close. In the server part, I used an `observeEvent` on the `b_auth` (*Auth* button ID
) and put the `removeModal()` function. When I click the *Auth* button, the modal does not close.

```
library(shiny); library(shinydashboard)

fmodal <- function(){modalDialog(id = "authModal",title = "title", textOutput("modalMessage"), textInput("username", "username", value = "username"), passwordInput("password", "password", value = "password"), footer = tagList(
      actionButton("b_auth", "Auth"), modalButton("Cancel")))
}

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"), dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Accueil", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")))), dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
fmodal() ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$b_auth, {
    removeModal() })}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the modal to the server works:

```
library(shiny); library(shinydashboard)

fmodal <- function(){modalDialog(id = "authModal",title = "title", textOutput("modalMessage"), textInput("username", "username", value = "username"), passwordInput("password", "password", value = "password"), footer = tagList(
    actionButton("b_auth", "Auth"), modalButton("Cancel")))
}

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"), dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Accueil", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")))), dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "dashboard"))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    showModal(fmodal())
    
    observeEvent(input$b_auth, {
        removeModal() })}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```